# Allow_Other with fusepy?

Tags: python, fuse

I have a 16.04 ubuntu server with [b2_fuse](https://github.com/sondree/b2_fuse/issues) mounting my b2 cloud storage bucket which uses pyfuse.  The problem is, I have no idea how I can pass the allow_other argument like with FUSE!  This is an issue because other services running under different users cannot see the mounted drive.

Does anybody here have some experience with this that could point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inside of file `b2fuse.py` if you change the line:

```
FUSE(filesystem, mountpoint, nothreads=True, foreground=True)
```

*to*

```
FUSE(filesystem, mountpoint, nothreads=True, foreground=True,**{'allow_other': True})
```

the volume will be mounted with `allow_other`.

Comment: Simply adding `allow_other=True` to the `FUSE()` arguments worked for me...